# UICollectionView Loading cells one by one from API

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, cells

I am using Flickr's API to retrieve images

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    photoURLString =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_m.jpg",
     [photo objectForKey:@"farm"], [photo objectForKey:@"server"],
     [photo objectForKey:@"id"], [photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];

    [self.photoURLsLargeImage addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURLString]]]];
    [self.flickrCollectionView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"photoURLsLareImage: %@\n\n", photoURLString);
    [self.flickrCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.flickrCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
```

and instead of waiting them all to load, and finally do

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    // cast uicollectionviewcell into instance of customcell
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    [cell.titleLabel setImage:[self.photoSmallImageData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    return cell;
}
```

I would like to load the cells one by one instantly after they've been retrieved from Flickr's API. I guess I have to do it in my connection method, but I cannot access my cells from there.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Tell the collection view to start off with zero cells, and insert cells once the corresponding image has been received.

Answer (score 0):

Directly accessing the Cells from the connection method is not a good practice.
 Ideally the design should be "Controller <-> FlickrManager <-> HTTPManager" All your connection code should reside in HTTPManager.
 FlickrManager should inform the controller about the new image addition.

Comment: This does not answer the OP.